# How to use array formula to return an array of sums in Excel

Tags: excel

eg, we have

```
 1  2  4
 3  4  5
 4  5  5
 2  4  5
```

I would like a array formula that returns an ARRAY = {7,12,14,11} Note it is not text, it is an array can be used in other array formula.

Currently i am using {=A1:A4+B1:B4+C1:C4+D1:D4}, however if the number of column is huge I cannot handle it manually.

Comment: @colinfang Is it possible for you to add a sum column (even if temporarily) to your data then grab an array from that? I would think this would be a very easy solution.

Comment: @Gaffi I wish the formula would dynamically reference to the data source without any temp cells. In your way if the temp column is deleted and data source is changed, then the outcome would be wrong

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this evaluates to the required array and could be extended to larger ranges:

`=MMULT(A1:C4,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A1:C4)^0))`

Comment: I like it! +1 - possible alternative `=SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1:C4,ROW(A1:C4)-ROW(A1),0,1))`

Comment: thanks you, I use this finally: MMULT(A1:C4,TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:C1,1,1)))

Comment: To sum the columns instead:
`=TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A1:C4),IF(A1:A4,1,1)))`

Comment: And how would you go about it if you wanted to skip some rows? Say you wanted `A1:C1`, `A2:C2` and `A4:C4`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is a lifesaver. Been thinking of how to do this with the new spill functions.

Answer (score 1):

When your matrix starts at A1 you can use:

```
=VERKETTEN("{";SUMME(A1:C1); ",";SUMME(A2:C2);",";SUMME(A3:C3);",";SUMME(A4:C4);"}")
```

This is of course for the german version. But "SUMME" should be SUM and "VERKETTEN" should be CONCATENATE. I'm sure you will find it in the help.

then it will be:

```
=CONCATENATE("{";SUM(A1:C1); ",";SUM(A2:C2);",";SUM(A3:C3);",";SUM(A4:C4);"}")
```

Even shorter:

```
="{"&SUM(A1:C1)&","&SUM(A2:C2)&","&SUM(A3:C3)&","&SUM(A4:C4)&"}"
```

For more you might need to use scripts that can handle loops etc.