# Formula for summing up progressive column values

Tags: excel-formula

I have a formula that calculates certain value using column values.

```
=Sheet2!B3*Sheet2!B2/SUM(Play!B3:B10)
```

Now where I am struggling is I want to do apply the same formula for all columns from `B` to `Z` and then sum them up in to a single value.

Something like

```
=SUM((Sheet2!B3 * Sheet2!B2/SUM(Play!B3:B10)), Sheet2!C3 * Sheet2!C2/SUM(Play!C3:C10)),.....)
```

Comment: Please format your code, and provide additional context **in the post, not the comments**

Comment: I think your best bet here is to do that sum in `B11`, copy across from `B` to `Z` then sum up the total. Otherwise you are going to end up with a hell of a big formula.

Comment: Did you try your formula? What worked and what didn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SUMPRODUCT` formula takes arrays of numbers and multiplies the numbers at each index together, then sums up the products.

The first two references are simple, but the third required more thought. (h/t to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9686453/2472738)).

```
   =SUMPRODUCT(Sheet2!B3:Z3,Sheet2!B2:Z2,1/TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(Play!B3:Z10),IF(Play!B3:B10,1,1))))
```

Note: This is an Array formula, so after you paste it in, you must press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`, and not just `Enter`.  It can easily be adapted to grow/shrink according to your needs.