# Excel multiple conditions per row in multiple rows (array or script solutions welcome) (Enterprise Turnover Thresholds)

Tags: arrays, excel, multiple-conditions

I'm putting together a sheet that calculates whether a group of enterprises meets certain turnover thresholds in several countries.

Column A are the countries (line 2=global; line 4-34 = EU member states); columns C-H are each enterprise's turnover (globally and in each EU member state).

Four criteria must be met, I'm struggling with no (iii). By way of background, criterion (ii) is:

*(ii) a combined turnover of all the merging firms over € 100 million in each of at least three Member States*

I found the solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685648/how-to-use-array-formula-to-return-an-array-of-sums-in-excel).

```
{=IF(SUM(IF(MMULT(C4:H31+0;TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C4:H31)^0))>=100*10^6; 1; 0))>=3; TRUE; FALSE)}
```

Criterion (iii) is

*(iii) a turnover of over €25 million for each of at least two of the firms in each of the three Member States included under (ii)*

When splitting up the two criteria in their own arrays I get correct true/false values for each country:
*Combined turnover over 100 Mio in a member state*

```
{=IF(MMULT(C4:H31+0;TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C4:H31)^0))>=100*10^6;TRUE;FALSE)}
```

and

*turnover for each of at least two of the firms of more than 25 Mio in a member state*

```
{=IF((MMULT(IF(C4:H31>=25*10^6;1;0);TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C7:H34)^0)))>=2;TRUE;FALSE)}
```

However combining these two formulas into one with IF(AND()) doesn't work

```
{=IF(AND(MMULT(C4:H31+0;TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C4:H31)^0))>=100*10^6;(MMULT(IF(C4:H31>=25*10^6;1;0);TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C4:H31)^0)))>=2);TRUE;FALSE)}
```

Is there a way of doing this, either by using arrays (preferred) or VBA?

Thanks a lot!

ElEsido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two formulae work fine separately as you say. What they are both doing is to give you a column vector of 1's and 0's which you can get a count from just by summing the elements.

To combine them you need to do a scalar multiply of each pair of elements so that you end up with another column vector which you can count in the same way so it looks like this:-

```
=SUM(IF(MMULT(C4:H10+0,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C4:H10)^0))>=100, 1, 0)*IF((MMULT(IF(C4:H10>=25,1,0),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C7:H10)^0)))>=2,1,0))
```

To keep things simple I have been testing it just on a few lines of data so you will need to scale it up to your actual data and put the millions back in.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Tom! Taking your formula and putting it into a IF(...>=3;TRUE;FALSE) exactly gives me what I need! Thank you again!